# if else statement between datetime but disregard time

Tags: c#, datetime, operands

Can you help me in removing the time in my code or rather correct my code for possible errors.
Thanks. Here's my code and ill state the error later.

```
else if (this.dateTimePicker1.Value != DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        this.chkBxLessNinety.Enabled = false;
                        string dateInString = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(_dr[4]));
                        DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
                        DateTime datelimit = startdate.AddDays(90);
                        //string date = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(datelimit.Date).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"));

                        string mydate1 = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
                        if (mydate1 > datelimit)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Sync data more or equal to 90 days");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
```

the line if (mydate1 > datelimit) shows an error which says > cannot be applied as operand of type string an datetime.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Retagged. This is not C++

Comment: Yes this is not C++. It is C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compare `DateTime`s with each other. Since you want to exclude the time portion then the `Date` property will make both dates at midnight hour.

```
 DateTime mydate1 = this.dateTimePicker1.Value;
 if (mydate1.Date > datelimit.Date)
  {
          MessageBox.Show("Cannot Sync data more or equal to 90 days");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.ToShortDateString()`

And also:

```
string dateInString = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(_dr[4]));
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Parse(dateInString);
```

Don't convert from DateTime to string and then back to DateTime, it's pointless

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `>` to compare a string and a DateTime. Instead, you should replace

```
string mydate1 = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

with

```
DateTime mydate1 = this.dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

This way, you'll be comparing things of the same type (`DateTime`).